# LCD Panel EM Interfereance Issue

Tags: video, display

I have a Pavilion 690-0024 running Windows 10 1909 with a Radeon RX 580 using driver version 26.20.14038.2009. Just recently I installed 32gigs of ram, everything has been fine, but in the last two weeks I have been getting some interference with my video signal. Im driving two LCD flat panel displays using HDMI connections. The problem I am experiencing happens on both screens.

I have attached two images that can act as a comparison of what the problem looks like:

[image: Normal Screenshot of display problem]
[image: Problem Screenshot of display problem]

The issue is two fold:

1. If I press the caps lock key, certain colors will change/flip. In these screenshots, you will notice that the green button turned to pink.
2. Intermittently, or upon waking the machine from sleep I will get
   artifacts that follow my mouse cursor, restarting the machine seems to fix the problem.

This is the first time I have experience this kind of EMI. I purchased some [Triple-shield HDMI cables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K7JN096), but now I am thinking that it might be another issue outside of the cables. I wanted to know if anyone could suggest a course of action to troubleshooting this if the cables don't fix the problem.

Comment: Are these direct screenshots, or did you "_mock them up_"? If they are screenshots, then the issue is not related to shielding or EMI, but is either in software, or in the framebuffer / compositing / RAM (potentially either graphics or system) pipeline...

Comment: These are direct screenshots. I only put red boxes around the problematic areas. What would be the best way to to troubleshoot this then? I would start with checking the system ram since I just recently upgraded that.

Comment: Swap out the system RAM, and see if that helps. Does this occur for anything other than your browser (i.e: games / video playback / word processing / etc...). Have you / can you update your graphics drivers? Can you use onboard graphics or a different graphics card?

Comment: Yea it happens in all applications. I updated the graphics drivers, but that did not fix the problem. I will try to swap out the ram and test the onboard video to see if I can reproduce the problem. I will not be back to my studio until the 15th of July 2020. So i will try that then and report back.

Answer (score 0):

So I couln't figure out the problem. I tried updating the drivers and changing the cables but that did not seem to fix the problem. I reinstalled windows 10 clean and that seemed to fix the problem and am not experiencing the problem any longer. maybe it was some incompatibility with drivers/software... no clue.